# getExternalStorageDirectory() issue in HTC devices

Tags: java, android

I tried to use getExternalStorageDirectory() in samsungs, Sony etc, but in HTC using android 2.2 FROYo if I remember good, causes an exception.

Any idea how to fix that or find external storage path in HTC devices?

My code looks like ->

```
 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + path);
```

Thanks to all

Comment: describing the exception might help...

Comment: I have not logs because I have not acces physically to the devices I have tested.

Comment: Any idea how to fix that?